# CakePHP restful routes

Tags: php, api, rest, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I cannnot find anything useful about this. I am trying to create RESTful routing. Here is what I want my routes to look like:

```
`GET`    routes to `RecipesController::api_index() //instead of RecipesController::index()`
`POST`   routes to `RecipesController::api_add() //instead of RecipesController::add()`
`PUT`    routes to `RecipesController::api_edit($id) //instead of RecipesController:edit($id)`
`DELETE` routes to `RecipesController::api_delete($id) //instead of RecipesController:delete($id)`
```

I do not know how to do this, here is what I have so far:

```
Router::resourceMap(array(
    array('prefix'=>'api', 'action' => 'index', 'method' => 'GET', 'id' => false),
    array('prefix'=>'api', 'action' => 'view', 'method' => 'GET', 'id' => true),
    array('prefix'=>'api', 'action' => 'add', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => false),
    array('prefix'=>'api', 'action' => 'edit', 'method' => 'PUT', 'id' => true),
    array('prefix'=>'api', 'action' => 'delete', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'id' => true),
    array('prefix'=>'api', 'action' => 'update', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => true)
));

Router::mapResources('recipes', array('prefix'=>'api'));
```

In my `core.php` I have the following:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('api'));
```

Cake returns this:

> 404 missing Recepies::api_1()

Here is the [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html) documentation I go by

Also, any other suggestions about proper RESTful API design are greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you can do this

```
Router::mapResources('recipes', array('prefix'=>'api'));
```

and that will give you the expected urls. You have to define the prefixes also, like @johhniedoe pointed out.

[This](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/class-Router.html#_mapResources) is the api doc where I read that from (it's for v2.0, but works since v1.3), maybe it'll help. The important part is where it says

> 'prefix' - URL prefix to use for the generated routes. Defaults to
>   '/'.

for the options. So if you activate the prefix and add it to `mapResources`, you wouldn't need to do anything more to have what you want. If the routes you want are the default, you don't need to use `resourcesMap` or the other route you define, `mapResources` should handle all that on its own.

**EDIT:**

If the defaults need override

```
Router::resourceMap(array(
    array('prefix'=>'api', 'action' => 'index', 'method' => 'GET', 'id' => false),
    array('prefix'=>'api', 'action' => 'view', 'method' => 'GET', 'id' => true),
    array('prefix'=>'api', 'action' => 'add', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => false),
    array('prefix'=>'api', 'action' => 'edit', 'method' => 'PUT', 'id' => true),
    array('prefix'=>'api', 'action' => 'delete', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'id' => true),
    array('prefix'=>'api', 'action' => 'update', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => true)
));

Router::mapResources('recipes', array('prefix'=>'api'));
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This did not work for me :( It works for GET but when I have DELETE /api/recepies/1 it returns 404 missing Recepies::api_1(). I want it to go to REcepies::api_delete(1) Any ideas how to fix it? I get that DELETE /api/recepies/delete/1 would work, but I am trying to stay away from that.

Comment: I'm assuming "receipies" is a typo, right? Check with all other methods, if it works for GET and all others but DELETE it may be a problem with the function calling the REST action. If there's no error on that part, try overriding the defaults with `resourceMap` (i'll update the answer for that)

Comment: It doesnt work for any of it, I just used DELETE As an example. Thanks I will try that and if it works I will mark the answer as accepted. And thanks for getting back to me on this.

Comment: I get the same thing as last time - returns 404 missing Recepies::api_1(). This should be pretty simple, I don't know why it doesnt work at all as expected. I don't really have any other routes that could be messing this thing up.

Comment: I'm debugging in the dark here now... But let's see. I think cake is not recognizing the call method correctly, so is not associating the routes like `recipes/1` to be REST. Could you update your question with the code you're using to test this? Also, for funsies, try it with `recipes/1.html` (or the format you want and have the view already made)

Answer (score 0):

In Config/core.php:124 for me ( depends on your version ) there is definition of prefixes with them you can achieve what you want.

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('api'));
```

You may also find this link helpful: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#using-additional-conditions-when-matching-routes

have a good one.